# SQL Server String Split to Column

Tags: sql-server, string, split

I have a function that accepts a VARCHAR field which I then need to parse and group into separate columns.

Below is a sample of the input data:

```
@input_data = '109.1|1|3.3|5.7|7.9,106.2|2|2.5|2.5|3.0,126.4.2|3|8.2|6.4|3.9'
```

The output data should look like this:

```
ID        SEQ   SCORE1   SCORE2   SCORE3
109.1     1     3.3      5.7      7.9
106.2     2     2.5      2.5      3.0
126.4.2   3     8.2      6.4      3.9
```

As you can see, I use a comma to delimit the input data and split them into rows. But my problem really comes in when I try to split each row data into their respective columns. I understand I can use `PARSENAME` for this but i'm concerned about the usage of the dot in the ID field and the SCORE fields.

So far, I have the following query which isn't really doing what I want it to do.

```
 SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(ms.value, '|', '.'), 5) AS ID,
        PARSENAME(REPLACE(ms.value, '|', '.'), 4) AS SEQ,
        PARSENAME(REPLACE(ms.value, '|', '.'), 3) AS SCORE1,
        PARSENAME(REPLACE(ms.value, '|', '.'), 2) AS SCORE2, 
        PARSENAME(REPLACE(ms.value, '|', '.'), 1) AS SCORE3   
 FROM   string_split(@input_data , ',') ms
```

Comment: Have you considered using a table valued parameter instead of multiple level delimited strings? What you have here violates 1NF and is a PITA to work with. PARSENAME only goes 4 deep so your logic won't work anyway.

Comment: Yes, I have a few table types in place but i'm not sure how the front-end would populate that before sending it to the function so I figured accepting a string would be easier? (if that makes sense). Thanks for the response.

Comment: It might save you 10 minutes in front end code but is going to generate a lot of effort in a query to do this. Don't know what front end you are using but splitting this apart is ugly in t-sql.

Comment: I'll reconsider this option, then. Thank you!

Comment: Depending on which version of SQL Server you're on, sending the message from the front-end in an XML or JSON string would make the back-end effort much easier.

Comment: I am running on SQL Server 2016. What would you suggest be the most efficient method to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way you could do this. I am using DelimitedSplit8K from Jeff Moden which you can find here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ The biggest advantage this splitter has is the ordinal position which is missing in string_split.

Notice how you have to split first on commas and then again on pipes. Finally you have to use conditional aggregation to shove it all back together. For a couple rows this isn't horrible but passing a table valued parameter is a million times more efficient than parsing strings to reassemble into consumable data.

```
declare @input_data varchar(200) = '109.1|1|3.3|5.7|7.9,106.2|2|2.5|2.5|3.0,126.4.2|3|8.2|6.4|3.9'

select ID = max(case when x2.ItemNumber = 1 then x2.Item end)
    , SEQ = max(case when x2.ItemNumber = 2 then x2.Item end)
    , SCORE1 = max(case when x2.ItemNumber = 3 then x2.Item end)
    , SCORE2 = max(case when x2.ItemNumber = 4 then x2.Item end)
    , SCORE3 = max(case when x2.ItemNumber = 5 then x2.Item end)
from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@input_data, ',')x
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(x.item, '|') x2
group by x.ItemNumber
```

Comment: This works! Thank you! I'll keep this in the back burner while I also study different other ways to achieve this while keeping optimal performance in mind. :)

Comment: If you're on 2012+ @Smiley, I suggest having a look at [Delimitedsplit8k_lead](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/); which includes an improvement to Jeff's already Brilliant solution by Eirikur Eiriksson.